# How old is the expression "as if"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, expressions

It's a pretty simple question, but just to clarify, I am talking about the expression used by itself, not just in a sentence.

So *not*:

> — Have you seen Ted?
>   — Yes! He flew through here as if his pants were on fire!

But rather:

> — Why are you denying it? You clearly like her...
>   — Me, like *her*? As if.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *OED* dates it to circa 1903, from the book *The Pit: A Story of Chicago* by Frank Norris, with this citation :

> 'Maybe he'll come up and speak to us.’ ‘Oh, as if!’ contradicted Laura.

The Merriam-Webster reference is probably to the Old English use of "as if" in in the sense 'as the case would be if'.

Comment: Thanks, Barrie. When you say "very early", did it give a date?

Comment: Ok, a little Googling has revealed that quote to be from "The Pit: A Story of Chicago" by Frank Norris. Google Books has this dated as 1798, which is clearly a misunderstanding by the person who digitized it. It was apparently actually first published in 1902. So very early 20th century indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster records its first use in the 13th century.

Comment: As a stand-alone expression?

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no example given. My guess is that no, it was referring to its use as a conjunction. However, they aren't as different as you might think. "As if" as an expression is an elliptic form of "As if that were true", so the meaning stays the same.